# InlineQueryResultArticle - thumb_url uploaded image

Tags: python-telegram-bot

Is there an option to use an image uploaded to telegram (`file_id` couldn't do it) inside `InlineQueryResultArticle thumb_url`?

notes:
I tried to get the file path using `getfile()` but it didn't do the trick.
even tried to upload a very small image size with no luck.
I'd like to ignore the `InlineQueryResultCachedPhoto` option since the design is not the same

any thoughts?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also checked that the telegram does not show the uploaded image, I think it is better to give the address of the picture directly.

Comment: I am using apache file server and saving profile images there. I am passing image's address in file server to thumb_url field, but still telegram does not want to show it.